# 2D and 1D numpy array in a for loop saving into files

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, slice

## Explanation of the problem

Given two 2D numpy arrays and one 1D numpy array:

```
F =  np.array[[-3764.9303402755891, -3764.9303494098212, -3764.9304257856452, -3764.9306329129422], [-3764.9338022566421, -3764.9338129752682, -3764.9338970928361, -3764.9341184863633]]

T =  np.array[[ 10.,   30.1,  50.2,  70.3],
 [ 10.,   30.1,  50.2,  70.3]]

V =  np.array[ 226.331804,  228.817957]
```

I would like to generate 4 files:

```
# F_10.0K.dat:
226.331804   -3764.9303402755891
228.817957   -3764.9338022566421

# F_30.1K.dat:
226.331804    -3764.9303494098212
228.817957    -3764.9338129752682

# F_50.2K.dat:
226.331804    -3764.9304257856452
228.817957    -3764.9338970928361

# F_70.3K.dat:
226.331804     -3764.9306329129422
228.817957     -3764.9341184863633
```

## My attempts:

I noticed that these two slicing operations:

```
print ' F_all[:,0] = ', F_all[:, 0]
print ' F_all[:,1] = ', F_all[:, 1]
```

return:

```
 F_all[:,0] =  [-3764.93034028 -3764.93380226]
 F_all[:,1] =  [-3764.93034941 -3764.93381298]
```

which is the 2nd column of the first two files: `F_10.0K.dat` and `F_30.1K.dat`.

So, I can loop:

```
F_all_each_V_at_cte_T = []
for indx in range(0, cols):
   aux = F_all[:,indx]
   print ' F_all[:, indx] = ', F_all[:,indx]
   F_all_each_V_at_cte_T.append(aux)

print 'F_all_each_V_at_cte_T = ', F_all_each_V_at_cte_T

output_array = np.vstack((VOLUME_EACH, F_all_each_V_at_cte_T)).T
np.savetxt('F_vs_V_10.0K.dat', output_array, header="Volume    F at 10.0K", fmt="%0.13f")
```

The result is:

```
F_all_each_V_at_cte_T =  [array([-3764.93034028, -3764.93380226]), array([-3764.93034941, -3764.93381298]), array([-3764.93042579, -3764.93389709]), array([-3764.93063291, -3764.93411849])]

# Volume    F at 10.0K
226.3318040000000 -3764.9303402755891 -3764.9303494098212 -3764.9304257856452 -3764.9306329129422
228.8179570000000 -3764.9338022566421 -3764.9338129752682 -3764.9338970928361 -3764.9341184863633
```

This nearly achieves the solution, however, all the columns are printed. How can I generate the above files ?

Comment: `np.array[ 226.331804,  228.817957]` is not valid Python syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `F` and `V` (I added () to make valid Python statements):

```
In [147]: F =  np.array([[-3764.9303402755891, -3764.9303494098212, -3764.930425
     ...: 7856452, -3764.9306329129422], [-3764.9338022566421, -3764.93381297526
     ...: 82, -3764.9338970928361, -3764.9341184863633]])
In [148]: V =  np.array([ 226.331804,  228.817957])
In [149]: F.shape
Out[149]: (2, 4)
In [150]: V.shape
Out[150]: (2,)
```

Since your `F` values differ on the small decimals it's a little tricky to figure out how you want to pair up values.  But this appears to be what you want:

```
In [152]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     print(np.column_stack((V,F[:,i])))

[[  226.331804   -3764.93034028]
 [  228.817957   -3764.93380226]]
[[  226.331804   -3764.93034941]
 [  228.817957   -3764.93381298]]
[[  226.331804   -3764.93042579]
 [  228.817957   -3764.93389709]]
[[  226.331804   -3764.93063291]
 [  228.817957   -3764.93411849]]
```

This isn't showing all the decimal values, but that's just a default numpy display issue.  I'm using `column_stack` as a convenient way of concatenating two 1d arrays as columns.  I could just as well have used `stack` or `concatenate` with the appropriate dimensions adjustment.

Doing the same with `savetxt`:

```
In [153]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     np.savetxt('foo%s'%i,(np.column_stack((V,F[:,i]))))
     ...:     
In [154]: cat foo0
2.263318040000000053e+02 -3.764930340275589060e+03
2.288179570000000069e+02 -3.764933802256642139e+03
In [155]: cat foo1
2.263318040000000053e+02 -3.764930349409821247e+03
2.288179570000000069e+02 -3.764933812975268211e+03
```

This uses the default `savetxt` formatting.  You could use what ever you prefer.

You could use `T` values to create the file names instead.  `foo%s`%T[0,i]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The `np.column_stack` is great. I have been thinking quite a long time on this... please see my answer, I think I have managed it to achieve it by looping. Please feel free to comment my approach and we can optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

For the better-shown matrix, you can use **`pprint`**, such as following code:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint('your-matrix')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `@hpaulj`'s answer:

```
F =  np.array([[-3764.9303402755891, -3764.9303494098212, -3764.9304257856452, -3764.9306329129422], [-3764.9338022566421, -3764.9338129752682, -3764.9338970928361, -3764.9341184863633]])    
V =  np.array([ 226.331804,  228.817957])
T =  np.array([[ 10.,   30.1,  50.2,  70.3], [ 10.,   30.1,  50.2,  70.3]])

for i in range(len(V)):
    np.savetxt('foo%s'%i,(np.column_stack((V, F[:,i]))))
```

I thought that this could also be achieved using the following loop:

```
rows = F_all.shape[0]
cols = F_all.shape[1]

cols_T = T.shape[1]
rows_T = T.shape[0]

for indx, t  in zip(range(0, cols), range(0, cols_T) ):
   aux_T = T[:,t]
   aux_F = F_all[:,indx]

   output_array = np.vstack((VOLUME_EACH, aux_F)).T
   np.savetxt('F_vs_V_%0.2fK.dat'  %aux_T[0], output_array, header="Volume           F at %0.2fK" %aux_T[0], fmt="%0.13f")
```

As shown here, the files produced are the same:

`cat foo0` :

```
2.263318040000000053e+02 -3.764930340275589060e+03
2.288179570000000069e+02 -3.764933802256642139e+03
```

`cat foo1`:

```
2.263318040000000053e+02 -3.764930349409821247e+03
2.288179570000000069e+02 -3.764933812975268211e+03
```

`cat F_vs_V_10.00K.dat`:

```
# Volume           F at 10.00K
226.3318040000000 -3764.9303402755891
228.8179570000000 -3764.9338022566421
```

`cat F_vs_V_30.10K.dat`:

```
# Volume           F at 30.10K
226.3318040000000 -3764.9303494098212
228.8179570000000 -3764.9338129752682
```